# Is there any logic in just maxing tempdb and never having it change size?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The reason I ask it we have a dedicated RAID10 array with ~150GB for the tempdb (the "t" drive).  It is only used for storing tempdb.  The t drive isn't used by by SQL Server or any other process for anything else.

Our DBA has tempdb setup with 15GB initial size and autogrow 20% increments.  Everytime the server starts it resized to 15GB and then over the course of the day grows to ~80GB (on average).  Now IT is looking into making initial size larger say 30 or 40GB but given the drive is ONLY used for tempdb my thinking is why not "max it" right away.

Is the any negative effect to simply create 4 data files in the primary group for tempdb give them each an initial size of 30GB (120GB total), turn autogrow off and be done with it?

Are there any limits on SQL Server ability to span multiple tempdb data files in one query?  i.e. will it cause problems if the tempdb has say 70GB total free but the file used by one process is full (30 of 30GB used)?

Comment: It's a pretty terrible idea to turn off `autogrow` on `tempdb` since if it hits the limit your queries will just die...

Comment: I guess my thinking is that autogrow or not the limit is the size of the disk at ~137GB usable.  So 120GB fixed tempdb or 120GB tempdb which can autogrow to 137GB didn't seem like much of a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would size them to about 100GB and leave autogrow on, this way you don't have to wait for it to grow every time, I would also add multiple files

> Is the any negative effect to simply
>   create 4 data files in the primary
>   group for tempdb give them each an
>   initial size of 30GB, turn autogrow
>   off and be done with it?

Sounds like a good plan to me, however I would leave autogrow on just in case someone decides to do a sort operation on a big table which doesn't have an index on that column

See also here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966534.aspx

- It is recommended to have .25 to 1
  data files (per filegroup) for each
  CPU on the host server.
- This is especially true for TEMPDB
  where the recommendation is 1 data
  file per CPU.
- Dual core counts as 2 CPUs; logical
  procs (hyperthreading) do not.

Comment: Couldn't he have an issue with autogrow off, though?  If you presize it shouldn't really matter, but if tempdb needed to grow it could cause an issue.

Comment: I see I missed the autogrow part in my answer below the quote, I will change it

Comment: The system has 16 cores so say we went with 8 data files.  

To expand upon the point is there any advantage to going with 8x 12GB datafiles with autogrow on (drive maxes out at 137GB) or just go with 8x 17GB data files fixed with no autogrow.

Is there any disadvantage to just maxing out the tempdb to all (or maybe 95%+) usable space on drive rather than having a smaller tempdb which will eventually grow to that size anyways.

Comment: I would size it as much as you can, this way it never needs to grow, you are not using the t drive for anything else anyway

Answer (score 1):

We have found it very useful to create large TempDB data and log files.  Any actions that limit server OS activities such as resizing TempDB increase server efficiencies.  We have a 16 processor machine with 113 GB dedicated to TempDB data space.  This machine is dedicated to large SSIS ETL processes, thus resulting in mass data operations.

The bulk of our ETL operations spawn up to  4 SQL threads.  After initially configuring a TempDB file for each processor (16), we quickly realized via performance monitoring that our configuration was forcing SQL\windows to unnecessarily span the multiple TempDB files.  We settled on 5 larger TempDB data files and realized performance improvements.  We have since moved on to a 24 processor box and are using 8 TempDB files.

Please note that this is a large data migration server; I’m sure transaction-oriented systems would still benefit from the recommended 1-1 processor to TempDB file configuration.  It should also be noted that having a large increase % on a TempDB file may force a critical transaction to take the windows operation hit and thus may not be appropriate for your specific application.